# Ignoring physical keyboard input when using SendWait

Tags: c#, sendkeys, virtual-keyboard

Have you ever tried to ignore special physical keyboard keys, when sending keys using [SendWait()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait?view=netframework-4.7.2)? It's easy to turn off `CAPSLOCK` using code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

void CheckCapslock()
{
    if(System.Windows.Forms.Control.IsKeyLocked(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.CapsLock)) 
    {
        const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
        const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
        keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
        keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,(UIntPtr)0);
    }
}
```

And turn on it again...
The bigger problem is when I try to remove `ALT`, because it's immediately turning on again. I'm tried also to use:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);
...
        SetKeyboardState(new byte[256]);
```

To zero current state of keyboard, but it's a lottery - sometimes I'm fast enough to send letter without any special keys, but sometimes I'm don't.

Is there any way to use [SendWait()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait?view=netframework-4.7.2), without any special keys from physical keyboard?

I know, that there is also [SendMessage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) function, which should "raw" key, but in my case - I can't use it.

Regards,

Hawex